# Why does xgboost produce the same predictions and nan values for features when using entire dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, boosting

### Summary

I am using Python v3.7 and xgboost v0.81. I have continuous data (y) at a US state level by each week from 2015 to 2019. I'm trying to regress on the following features to y: year, month, week, region (encoded). I've set the train as August 2018 and before and the test is September 2018 and onward. When I train the model this way, two weird things happen:

- feature_importances are all nan
- predictions are all the same (0.5, 0.5....)

### What I've tried

Fixing any of the features to a single variable allows the model to train appropriately and the two weird issues encountered previously are gone. Ex. year==2017 or region==28

### Code

#### (I know this is a temporal problem but this general case exhibits the problem as well)

```
X = df[['year', 'month', 'week', 'region_encoded']]
display(X)
y = df.target
display(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values, y.values, test_size=0.1)

model = XGBRegressor(n_jobs=-1, n_estimators=1000).fit(X_train, y_train)

display(model.predict(X_test)[:20])

display(model.feature_importances_)
```

#### Results - some of the predictions and the feature importances

```
year    month   week    region_encoded
0   2015    10  40  0
1   2015    10  40  1
2   2015    10  40  2
3   2015    10  40  3
4   2015    10  40  4

0    272.0
1     10.0
2    290.0
3     46.0
4    558.0
Name: target, dtype: float64

array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], dtype=float32)

array([nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Welcome, @dnly15! Could you print and update your question to show what `df['target']` and `df[[...]]` for y and X respectively looks like, please? Also could you pass df['target'].values and df[[...]].values to XGBoost just to be safe.

Comment: Also could you try scaling your X data with a standard scaler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the target variable has `NaN` in it, even just one, that is enough for many machine learning algorithms to break. This is usually because when an unhandled `NaN` is present in the target variable in the update step of many ML algorithms for example computing derivatives, the `NaN` propagates. Although, I cannot say too much about which step in XGBoost does this.

For example, the analytical solution for linear regression.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
from scipy import stats

y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
x = stats.norm().rvs((len(y), 3))

# Main effects estimate
m_hat = la.inv(x.T @ x) @ x.T @ y
>>> [nan nan nan]
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem, I had `NaN`s in my data when I thought I had removed them. Concise and helpful explanation, thanks SARose!